# getting hibernate session error in java

Tags: java, hibernate

i have this

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
        .configure("com/vaannila/service/hibernate.cfg.xml")
        .buildSessionFactory();

          Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

i get this error

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:542)
```

Answer (score 2):

You must set your hibernate.current_session_context_class in your hibernate.xml file.

Refer to the following: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-j2ee-currentsession

Answer (score 2):

have this entry in your cfg file.

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```